# Angular conditions on a template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have  a child component app-page-header , what I want is that if headerOptions.headerTitle !== 'Idle Disposition' then [titleData] = 'headerOptions.headerTitle' , if headerOptions.headerTitle === 'Idle Disposition' then [titleData]= "{{dealDetails?.dealType}}"

how do we implement this logic in angular syntax? thanks for any help.

#my current implementation

```
    <app-page-header
      [titleData]="headerOptions.headerTitle !== 'Idle Disposition' ? headerOptions.headerTitle : headerOptions.headerTitle ({{dealDetails?.dealType}})"
      [breadCrumbs]="headerOptions.breadCrumbs"
      [hasTabs]="false"
    >
<p>{{dealDetails?.dealType}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will display exactly what you describe:

```
[titleData]="headerOptions.headerTitle !== 'Idle Disposition' ? headerOptions.headerTitle : '{{dealDetails?.dealType}}'"
```

However it seems likely that you may want to display the value of dealDetails?.dealType instead of the exact text "{{dealDetails?.dealType}}" in which case you should be able to just use this:

```
[titleData]="headerOptions.headerTitle !== 'Idle Disposition' ? headerOptions.headerTitle : dealDetails?.dealType"
```

Comment: Hi Sir I got an error https://imgur.com/a/bk0yy1M

Comment: What is the actual error message? It should be right above what is visible in the screenshot.

Comment: this is the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/58XdPhD

Comment: It seems that headerOptions.headerTitle contains an object of some sort that is not comparable to a string. Make sure that headerOptions.headerTitle cnotains a string value or use a string property of the object to compare like: headerOptions.headerTitle.otherInfo.label !== 'Idle Disposition'